# UWP: how to run a task without slowing down?

Tags: c#, uwp, real-time, midi

i'm developing an uwp app in c# capable to play midi files. I created a ThreadPoolTimer to scan a tick of 1 ms and other ThreadPool to run an async task that launch the midi messages of files relative to the time scanned by tick. It works correctly however when i do some other operation with laptop it throw a slow down behaviour. Mainly when i turn the gui in background. I changed the ThreadPool.RunAsync() with a Task.Run() and it works better but i'm trying to understand what is the best way to do a real time app with uwp because i need to implement new tasks. Additionally, i want to change base priority of my app programmatically because it works better with high priority but i don't want to change it manually everytime.
Ho can i do this tasks? i'm searching on internet but i not found any useful information about this in uwp.

Thank you

Edit: I want to use this app for play music so i need to develop it with high performance feature. For this cause i need to launch it directly with high priority level.

maybe can i develop some library

Comment: The implementation of tasks uses the thread pool under the hood, the main benefit of tasks is that they allow you to focus less on the low-level aspects of multi-threading. So in general, unless you need the low-level control, we usually use Tasks. In addition, do you mean you want to change the priority of your uwp app in task manager?

Comment: Did you consider to change the priority of only that thread that actually does the real time stuff?

Comment: Hello again, i did a test changing  the ThreadPoolTimer for 1ms tick  with the DateTime class, so i use the system clock for time scanning and it works perfectly. Maybe i increase the priority of ThreadPoolTimer to solve this issue. I will try this. However is a good way using the system clock?  i'm not shure

Comment: It seems feasible to work with the system clock. for more details about ThreadPoolTimer, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer?view=winrt-19041).